# Spring Batch Processing Time Out Exception on Job status change

Tags: spring-batch, spring-jdbc, spring-batch-tasklet

We have the following Spring batch process that runs the batch job and its currently timing out with connecting with Postgresql database. If the job takes 20 minutes or 40 minutes, then the job runs fine and there is no exception. But, if the job takes more than 1 hour, then there is exception that's happening on the service.

#### Code Snippet

```java
public class FileListener {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        BatchJobEvent batchJobEvent = buildBatchJobEvent(event);
        BatchUtil.launchJob(batchJobEvent, applicationContext, jobLauncher);

    }
}
```

And the BatchUtil class is as follows, which starts the Spring batch job.

```java
public class BatchUtil {

    public static void launchJob(BatchJobEvent batchJobEvent, ApplicationContext applicationContext,
            JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        Job job = (Job) applicationContext.getBean(Utils.getValue(batchJobEvent.getJobName()));
        JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();

        JobParameters jobParameters = jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters();
        try {
            log.info("foobar: Trying to launch Job [{}], with parameters [{}]", job.getName(), jobParameters.toString());
            jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        } 
    }
}
```

When the batch job runs with file size that's big, the following exception is happening:

> {"@timestamp":"2023-03-06T16:59:01.366+00:00","@version":1,"message":"Error while extracting
> database name - falling back to empty error codes","logger_name":"org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory","thread_name":"pool-10-thread-3","level":"WARN","level_value":30000,"stack_trace":
> "org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed\n\tat
> org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:330)\n\tat
> org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:355)\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.persistSerializedContext(Jdb
> cExecutionContextDao.java:233)\n\tat org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.updateExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:161)\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext(SimpleJobRepository.java:209)\n\tat org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(T
> askletStep.java:451)\n\tat org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransacti
> onCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)\n\tat org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)\n
> \tat org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)\n\tat org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)\n\tat org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)\n
> \tat
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is
> closed\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnecti
> on.java:490)\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy163.getMetaData(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikar
> i.pool.ProxyConnection.getMetaData(ProxyConnection.java:361)\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.getMetaData(HikariProxyConnection.java)\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)\n\tat org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)\n\tat org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:394)\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:308)\n\tat
> org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:141)
> n\tat org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)\n\tat
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
> An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:333)\n\tat
> org.postgresql
> .jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)\n\tat
> org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:132)\n\tat
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)\n\tat
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.jav
> a)\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$0(JdbcTemplate.java:855)\n\tat
> org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)\n\t... 69 common frames
> omitted\nCaused by: java.io.EOFException: null\n\tat
> org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:295)\n\tat
> org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1947)\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)\n\t... 77 common

The hikari connection pool settings are as follows :

```
hikari:

      connection-init-sql: SELECT 1
      connection-test-query: SELECT 1
      connection-timeout: 30000
      idle-timeout: 30000
      maximum-pool-size: 20
      minimum-idle: 1
      pool-name: hikari
      validation-timeout: 300000
```

Please help on this.

Comment: Please share application.properties file or equivalent. Especially the part defining datasource, jdbc and hikari.

Comment: @Mar-Z , The following are the properties:    hikari:
      connection-init-sql: SELECT 1
      connection-test-query: SELECT 1
      connection-timeout: 30000
      idle-timeout: 30000
      maximum-pool-size: 20
      minimum-idle: 1
      pool-name: hikari
      validation-timeout: 300000

Comment: Please add property: keepalive-time: 300000 This should help keeping the connection to the database alive if it is idle for longer then 5 minutes.